# How can i make special live template in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, live-templates

I have been make Live Template in IntelliJ which name is `syso [ System.out.println($END$); ]`

But i want to make like `sout` or `par`. didn't find anything information.

[image: a busy cat]

How can i do this??

Comment: Could you please explain exactly which property you're looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not find the release number bringing this feature, but as of `2019.2.1` you can now edit and create custom `Postfix Completion` really easily in `File | Settings | Editor | General | Postfix Completion`.

> **Note:** to my knowledge, you cannot edit some built-in postfix templates (*e.g.*: `!`).

*Source:* https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-postfix-completion.html

Answer (score 1):

Each postfix live template is implemented as a custom Java class that performs the necessary transformation of the expression in the editor. The only way to add your own postfix template is to write a plugin.

You can find implementations of postfix live templates for Java [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/java/java-impl/src/com/intellij/codeInsight/template/postfix/templates/JavaPostfixTemplateProvider.java).